# "give it to dispatch"; "one per charge" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning

I really need help to understand the following dialogues from CSI: Vegas Season 1 Episode 9, I need to translate this.
What does **"Got to give it to dispatch"** mean in the following dialogue?

The investigators are talking:

- Construction crew came back to finish a road project that was dormant. Found a couple of bodies that must've been buried a few months back.
- **Got to give it to dispatch.** They can make anything sound routine.

And what does **"one per charge"** mean in this dialogue?

- You admit to tampering with evidence in those dozen cases we found, you'll be home in time to see your kid graduate high school.
- It's a great deal. 12 years with good behavior. **That's only one per charge.** But the confession really has to deliver.

I would appreciate any help.

I also struggle with this dialogue too: ;( ;( ;(

-You want to contain the damage at the civil trial.

-If Anson Wix can slime the crime lab with a widespread pattern of behavior, the number of wrongful imprisonment settlements could just about bankrupt the state.

Can someone interpret this with other words?

Comment: Although both these questions stem from the same show, they are two separate questions, which makes this question off-topic for this site. If you want the answer to both, please remove one and ask it in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Got to give it to Dispatch” is a sarcastic comment. “It” here means a prize or reward. “Dispatch” here means the “Dispatch Center” in a police department that is responsible for telling where specific patrol cars are immediately needed. The sarcasm here presumably means that the officer dispatching cars to the scene understated the severity of the situation.

“One per charge” means in this context “one year of jail time for each separate criminal offense that will be charged (prosecuted).”

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really struggle with this series.
Could you help me with this phrase too?
 "You want to contain the damage at the civil trial"

Comment: There is less context here. "Containing the damage at the civil trial" may mean "helping to prevent a loss in a civil suit, either in process or anticipated" or "helping to reduce the financial penalty after losing a civil suit, either in process or anticipated" or both.  You may well be able to refine which meaning is intended in the context of the story.